What does the values in the splits from XGBoost mean?
I have trained an XGBoost model in R with caret package.
The values in the variables were grouped in between 2 to 5 groups.
I have managed to extract all the splits, but the splitting values is not the raw grouped value, but something else.

Can I somehow find the real value for this split?
What exactly is this value from the model?
Does this value corresponds to the grouped value?




Variable
split condition
XGB value
Real value




Var1
lessThan
-132.25705
97.71 or -152.46


Var1
greaterOrEqual
-132.25705
97.71 or -152.46


Var2
lessThan
-48.036224
55.853485 or -14.946478



